# Communication between turtles in Netlogo

Tags: communication, netlogo

I am new to Netlogo. I was wondering if there is anyway to pass messages between two or more turtles, or one turtles to a group of turtles.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at "Communication-T-T Example", in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

NetLogo doesn't really have a built-in concept of "messages". Agents can simply perform actions, on themselves or on each other. For example, one turtle might turn another turtle red:

```
ask one-of turtles [
  ask one-of other turtles [
    set color red
  ]
]
```

If you want, you can conceive of this as one of the turtles sending the other turtle a "message". (NetLogo doesn't care how you conceive of it, the code behaves the same regardless.)

If you mean something specific by "pass messages", please improve your question to be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you!, i understand what you mean. Ill try it out.

Comment: Really helpful, thanks a lot